# how to exclude the non numerical integers from a data frame in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython

I have a data frame which comprises of datatypes integer, string, numeric etc. 
Something like below. I want to exclude all the variables which are non-numeric. is there any automated way in Python?

```
'data.frame':   891 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ PassengerId: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Survived   : int  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ Pclass     : int  3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ Name       : Factor w/ 891 levels "Abbing, Mr. Anthony",..: 109 191 358 277 16 559 520 629 417 581 ...
 $ Sex        : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ Age        : num  22 38 26 35 35 NA 54 2 27 14 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ Ticket     : Factor w/ 681 levels "110152","110413",..: 524 597 670 50 473 276 86 396 345 133 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
 $ Cabin      : Factor w/ 148 levels "","A10","A14",..: 1 83 1 57 1 1 131 1 1 1 ...
 $ Embarked   : Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","Q","S": 4 2 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 2 ...
```

After exclusion of numeric variables, my dataframe should look like the below:

```
'data.frame':   891 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ PassengerId: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Survived   : int  0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ Pclass     : int  3 1 3 1 3 3 1 3 3 2 ...
 $ Age        : num  22 38 26 35 35 NA 54 2 27 14 ...
 $ SibSp      : int  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 1 ...
 $ Parch      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 ...
 $ Fare       : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
```

Comment: @hpaulj - Sorry if this is not pandas. I am now transforming from R to python. So everything is new to me under python.

Comment: The reason why I asked about `pandas` is that that package (built on top of numpy) uses the 'dataframe' terminology.  In `numpy` we just have multidimensional arrays of uniform data type, and structured arrays with mixed data type fields.  May be you should add an `R` tag, so others with cross over experience can help.

Comment: @hpaulj - done. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `._get_numeric_data()`

```
import pandas as pd #import the pandas library
#creating a small dataset for testing
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PassengerId' :  [1, 2, 3], 
        'Name' : ['Abbing, Mr. Anthony', 'Ann, C', 'John, H'], 
        'Fare' : [7.25, 71.28, 7.92]})
#extract only the numeric column types
df2 = df1._get_numeric_data()
print(df2)
```

Or another option is `select_dtypes()`

```
df3 = df1.select_dtypes(include = ['int64', 'float64'])
print(df3)
```

Comment: have a question here. In my dataframe i have few numeric variables which are either logical values containing 0 or 1 and few categorical variables containing numeric values. Is there anyway to exclude that as well?

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity. Is there any similar function in R as well?

Comment: @Arun In `R`, if the `df1` is the `data.frame`,  we could use `df1[sapply(df1, is.numeric)]` to get only numeric columns or `Filter(is.numeric, df1)`